# How do I find the directory chruby.sh and auto.sh files to finalize installation of chruby?

Tags: macos, homebrew, chruby

I apologize in advance; I am new to all of this.

When I downloaded chruby via Homebrew, some "Caveats" came up, i.e., "Add the following to the ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc file ..." I closed my Terminal before following these instructions and now I do not know how to add to these files (as it seems the directory is different for each user?).  I've opened my home directory and can see hidden files, but I don't know where to begin to look to find the chruby.sh and auto.sh files mentioned in the Caveats.

How can I follow the Caveats and successfully install chruby?

Thank you and apologies again.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain information about `chruby` by running:

```
brew info chruby
```

You will obtain the caveats you are looking for:

```
==> Caveats
Add the following to the ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc file:
   source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh

To enable auto-switching of Rubies specified by .ruby-version files,
add the following to ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc:
   source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
```